# Rich Internet Applications with ExtJS: Which direction should I choose?

Tags: javascript, ria

I need some help in choosing the right way for my RIA. I do want to use a javascript widget library - possibly ExtJS. I'm not sure however if I should try to get around programming in Javascript through [ExtGWT](http://extjs.com/products/gxt/) or other solutions like [Rialto Python](http://rialto.improve-technologies.com/wiki/python). What are your experiences with web application frameworks that do not require you to program in Javascript? For instance, is it a big disadvantage to abandon technologies like jQuery if heading for GWT?

Comment: I wonder why this question is under EXTJS tag? If I get it right, the question is about non-Javascript experience?

Comment: I adjusted my question: It is not about non-Javascript websites, but about using Javascipt without programming in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You don't lose a ton of functionality in ext-gwt, but it's not a flawless import of ext either.

The things that most influence deciding about "compiling" JavaScript for me are:

- How happy will you be with added layers between the ext library and the Java library? Naturally, GWT needs glue to connect your JavaScript code to it's Java code. They library needs to be configured, and sometimes that's annoying.
- I find you generally get better help with the native libraries in general. A big bennie. The jQuery questions are knocked down pretty dang quick. I don't see many GWT questions come across the board. (maybe it just works! Now I sound like an Apple commercial)
- How much do I like to work in JavaScript. I love JavaScript code. I find it slightly annoying when I have to meddle with strict types in Java when I could be flying along in JavaScript.
- How will debugging/tinkering in JavaScript slow me down? Do you prefer a short work code/test cycle? The GWT style approach is beautiful in that if it compiles, it generally does what you think it will. (the cost is you lose immediacy, but most developers are used to that situation)

Oh, btw, [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) if you prefer that, but again, some of the power is in the plugins for jQuery, which, you'll have to write the glue for.

Comment: May be you don't loose "a ton of functionality" just half ton, but you loose millions of tons awsome thinks that you fill with JavaScript & ExtJs :)

Comment: @Zango And, perhaps since I've written this it has gotten better. I didn't look into the extgwt much since I've written this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main disadvantages to writing javascript is that it often works differently on different browsers. However, with something like jQuery, this is abstracted away from you. Note that the same is true for GWT.

Therefore, I'd say that if you are more comfortable writing swing apps, use GWT and if you are more comfortable writing web apps, use html combined with jquery or another javascript framework.

Comment: And the same is true with ExtJS.

Comment: ExtJS is cross browser framework, So with ExtJs there is not cross browser problems.