# ExtJS vs ExtGWT - Are they functionally equal?

Tags: extjs, gxt

Assuming a person has same level of expertise in JS and Java, Should he choose ExtJS or ExtGWT for a new project with Java / Spring server side backend,

1.Are they functionally equal?. All the widgets available in ExtJS are available in ExtGWT?

2.Or new widgets available in the ExtJS and they will be ported ExtGWT in next releases?.

I see that ExtJS 4 is coming. But ExtGWT is 3 only.

I could not find any comprehensive comparison between ExtJS and ExtGWT

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812401/rich-internet-applications-with-extjs-which-direction-should-i-choose and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673612/extgwt-vs-extjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have seen [ExtGWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/) releases
  usually trail [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
- You can compare the available
  capability/widgets by browsing
  through the "Samples and Demos" for
  [ExtGWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/examples/) and [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/)
- You also want to consider the
  availability of a **huge number of user
  [extensions and plugins available for ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Extensions)**

Considering the "same level of expertise" factor, I would chose a stack comprised of [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) (+ ExtDirect) + [directjngine](http://code.google.com/p/directjngine/) + Spring

Comment: I am accepting @amol's answer considering the first availability of new features.