# Decide between extJS and GWT

Tags: gwt, extjs

we're in the process of deciding our next web application framework strategy, and there's a lot to think about.

After going over several solutions, we've restricted our sight to 2 RIA frameworks: extJS and GWT.

Which one would you suggest between these two?

We're already experienced in jQuery, should it somehow matter.

Thanks.

Comment: what are your requirements?  What are your team's strengths?

Comment: Are you conisdering ExtJS 3, or ExtJS 4?

Comment: @Mchl: We don't exactly know by now, 'cause we're starting our process of evaluation. Could you please recap the differences?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: we're experienced in PHP and jQuery, but the need is for our next applications to be RIA-wise, mainly oriented to datagrids and graphs. Our goal is to provide as much as possible a "desktop" feeling with our next web applications.

Comment: The most obvious difference is that ExtJS4 is not generally avialable yet (though it is expected to be released within Q1 2011). There are several articles introducing new features on Sencha website, and it seems that a lot of how the framework works will change. I asked my question pretty much to draw your attention to this fact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is not possible to provide an objective answer to your question without being intimately familiar with your project's situation here are a few things to consider -

- [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) will require JavaScript expertise (in addition to the familiarity required with the ExtJS [api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) itself)
- Even if you use [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) for your front end, you will still need Java (or whatever server side language you choose) expertise for your server side logic.
- In comparision, with [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) you can do with lesser level of Javascript expertise. You do have to get to know the [GWT way](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) (and tools for) of development, the api, etc.
- Both will allow you to do whatever you want in terms of your front end capability.
- While comparing available widgets, etc consider the **huge number of [ExtJS extensions and plugins](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Extensions)** available. These are as valuable as the core ExtJS widgets in some situations.
- **[Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/)** seems like an option but I would rather use [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) ***OR***  [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) than use a combination of both unless there is a very specific reason.
- **If you have JavaScript expertise but no Java AND there is no specific reason to use Java, I would go for [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)** (and a server side language with simpler learning curve than Java)

(Very) Slightly related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886397/extjs-vs-extgwt-are-they-functionally-equal/4890074#4890074)

Answer (score 3):

My company faced the same decision about two years ago and decided to use ExtJS.  I'm happy with that decision.  Javascript is more flexible and less wordy than Java, and the Javascript edit/test cycle is very short.  Just save the change and refresh the browser.  And it's relatively easy to extend the ExtJS classes to add any needed feature.  Java changes require compilation and frequently require a server restart.  Those little interruptions are very expensive.

Ultimately, I think it comes down to whether you prefer working in Javascript or Java.  I prefer the flexibility and conciseness of Javascript, and the speed of zero-delay testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experienced with JavaScript then I think that ExtJS will seem natural (you need little in the way of JavaScript experience to use GWT).

On the other hand, I'd bet on GWT in the long run because it's backed by Google and has a lot of momentum; however, it might not be worth learning Java for in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the GWT propenents. But in your case, GWT does not look like a good option, because your team does not have experienced java developer. But if you consider to recruit an experienced java developer, GWT would be a better option for you. Otherwise, you should go with ExtJS.